# leaflet js: how to create tooltips for L.CircleMarker?

Tags: leaflet

I am wondering if there is a way to set the tooltip for L.CircleMarker?

```
var geojsonLayerVessel = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (latlng){
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 5,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        title: "test"
    });
}
});
```

tried the above code, but it is not working.

Comment: The title is only added when your marker has an icon, not to CircleMarkers.

Answer (score 1):

For GeoJSON layers you can listen to the 'featureparse' event to bind popups, as per [this example](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html). Something along these lines:

```
var geoJsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null,{
pointToLayer: function (latlng){
return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
    radius: 5,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
});

geoJsonLayer.on('featureparse', function(e){
//Now you can bind popups to features in the layer, and you have access to
//attributes on the GeoJSON object through e.properties:
e.layer.bindPopup('Hello! ' + e.properties.someProperty);
});

//now you add some some data to your layer and add it to the map....
geoJsonLayer.addGeoJSON(someGeoJson);
map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question is to add a tooltip, not a popup.

Comment: Except, as pointed out, you can't have a tooltip on a CircleMarker. So, there are two options: don't use a CircleMarker or DO use a popup. Since I'm pretty sure I can't use a DivIcon in a Canvas layer (which tbf probably didn't exist when the question was asked!) this would be the correct answer for rendering with a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for `CircleMarkers`.
But you can create a little `DivIcon` and style it with rounded corners.
`DivIcon`s do support the `'title'` option.

http://jsfiddle.net/63teycsq/1/

The function to provide as pointToLayer:

```
function (latlng){
    return L.marker(latlng, 
                    { icon : L.divIcon({ className : 'circle',
                                         iconSize : [ 5, 5 ]}),
                      title: 'test'});
}
```

And the div's styling:

```
div.circle {
    background-color: #ff7800;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
}
```

Comment: flup's fiddle was outdated. For those who still wonder, see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63teycsq/1/

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, in the latest versions of Leaflet, CircleMarker *does* have tooltips, so with the original code it could be instantiated as:

```
var geojsonLayerVessel = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (latlng){
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
        radius: 5,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    }).bindTooltip("test");
}
});
```